Paint bubbling and excessive flash after using Polyfilla
I've been struggling with an issue of trying to remove paint bubbles and excessively bad flash for a couple of months now, varying on many different techniques and products to try resolve the issue but none have worked so far.
A bit of extra context:

I've waited days for each coat to dry to see if it'd reduce the issue
I've used both Zinsser Peel Stop & Guardz
I've only encountered bubbling in areas that needed to be sanded or filled using polyfilla. I've attempted to resolve the bubbling by polyfilling over the bubbled areas after scraping the paint but it's very hard to get it sanded enough that the polyfill doesn't leave a texture on the wall (visible still after 3 coats) or over sanding which will result in bubbles from the prior layer.
Most of bubbles appear around corners of areas that had to be peeled (even after threating with Zinsser Peel Stop primer)
We're using Fleetwood Hazy Days Soft Sheen Acrylic as the base paint
This is a 2nd hand house we've just moved into and are a not aware of the specific types of paint that were used under. We're not sure if it could be reacting in any way with the others below since there are 2 different paints below our one.

Example of the bubbling:

Example of the flash:


is it humid where you are

A general thought is you may have an "off gassing" issue from incompatibility between some of the plethora of products you used on the wall.  I admit this is a guess as I do not have the chemical report of the products.  I just subscribe to the belief that the primer or any sealer used pre painting should be from the same manufacturer.

@Traveler in Ireland, virtually no humidity here

@RMDman in this case both the primer and sealer are from Zinsser

Are these walls plaster or drywall? If you are claiming that the walls have been primed and painted and are still seeing this, something is sucking the water out of the paint to cause it to dry unevenly. The bubbling could be caused by too much air entrainment in the Polyfill. Are you using a premix or rehydrating a dry powder?

@chdonncha, Sorry I was not clear. The paint and primer/ sealer should all be from the same manufacturer.

@DelphicOracle I'm painting on a plastered solid wall. For the Polyfill I'm using the premix, I've tried both the premade Polycell Polyfilla Multi Purpose & and the Smoothover variant, both with the same issue, even after cleaning the sanded surface with a damp cloth and brush even feeling the surface after to ensure there's no Pollyfilla dust or powder left on the wall

I'd be tempted to use Zinsser's BIN on the wall just to create an impermeable surface and then paint with your Fleetwood colour.
